# Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.ServiceCreationException : Failed while creating a ABC service

Tags: .net, biztalk

After deploying a set of services on QA environemnt, one orchestration is suspended with message

Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.ServiceCreationException : Failed while creating a ABC service.

In windows event log, I found:

Object of type 'XYZ.**Schemas_BFX_v01**' cannot be converted to type 'XYZ.**Schemas_BFX_v01**'.

any clue what causing this exception. same BizTalk msi was deployed on development server and its is working fine there.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error "Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.ServiceCreationException : Failed while creating a XXX service" is common if the server where an instance of the orchestration are about to start does not have the assembly in GAC.

Comment: I had my service gaced only on one server, not both!

Answer (score 1):

Do you possibly have the same schema deployed multiple times on the same server? Check the schemas node in the BizTalk administrator and see if there are any duplicates of the XYZ.Schemas_BFX_v01 schema.