# xlang/s engine event log entry: Failed while creating a X service. Object of type 'Y' cannot be converted to type 'Y'

Tags: service, biztalk

xlang/s engine event log entry: Failed while creating a X service.  Object of type 'Y' cannot be converted to type 'Y'.

This event log entry appears to be the same as what is discussed here:

[Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.ServiceCreationException : Failed while creating a ABC service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1293419/717860)

I've investigated the 2 solutions offered in this post, but neither fixed my problem.

I'm running BizTalk 2010 and am seeing the issue with a uniform sequential convoy.  Each instance of the orchestration is initially activated as expected.  All the shapes before the second receive shape execute without issue.  The problem occurs when the orchestration instance receives its second message.  Execution does not proceed beyond the receive shape that corresponds to this second message.

Using the Group Hub page, I can see that the second message is associated with the correct service instance. This service instance is suspended and the error message shown above appears in the event log.

Occasionally (about 1 out of every 5 times), the problem mentioned above does NOT occur.  That is, subsequent messages are process by the orchestration. I'm feeding in the same test files each time.  Even more interesting...the problem NEVER occurs if I set a break point (in Orchestration Debugger) on a Listen shape just before the second receive shape.

The fact that I don't see the problem when using the debugger makes me wonder if this is a timing issue.  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like I would have much control over the timing.

Does anyone have any idea about how to prevent this problem from occurring?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is there only a single BizTalk host server involved? It wouldn't surprise me if the issue was related to difficulty loading a required assembly from the GAC. If there were multiple BizTalk servers involved, it could be that one of them is the culprit (or only one of them isn't). Of course, it may not be that easy.

An alternative is the second answer on the other question to which you linked, stating to check that a required schema is not deployed more than once. I have had this problem before, and about the only way to figure out that this is what's going on is to look in the BizTalk Admin Console under `BizTalk Group > Applications > <AllArtifacts> > Schemas` and sort by the Target Namespace to see if there are any two (or more) rows with the same combination of Target Namespace and Root Name.

The issue could also be caused by a schema mismatch, where perhaps an older/different version of a schema is deployed than expected, and a field that is only sometimes there (hence why it sometimes works) causes a mismatch.

These are, of course, just theories, without the ability to look into your environment and see the actual BizTalk artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

I filed this issue with Microsoft.  It turns out that "the behavior is actually an existing design limitation with the way the XLANG compiler relies on type wrappers."  The issue resulted from an very specific scenario.  We had an orchestration with a message variable directly referencing a schema and another message variable referencing a multi-part message type based on the same schema.  The orchestration, schema, and multi-part message type were each defined in different projects.

Microsoft suggested that we modify one of the variables so that both referenced the schema or both referenced the MMT.  Unfortunately, keeping the variables as they were was critical for us.  We discovered (and Microsoft confirmed) that moving the definition of the MMT into the same project as the orchestration resolved the issue as well.